# Layout Appearing Different in Graphical Layout and on Actual Device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have follwoing XML layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView_player"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8.5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_indicator"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_play"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is appearing in my Graphical Layout like following.
[image]

But on My device it is Appearing like following.
[image]

in actual device right side is taking more area than assigned weight. I have tried many things but no success. What is wrong with my code???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably adjusting itself to the aspect ratio of the video.
Put the `VideoView` within another view with the correct weight.

Try this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8.5">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView_player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

...
```